# building array inside 2 loops

Tags: php, arrays, loops

can someone help me?
cause i cant figure it out.

lets say i have a database with two tables the one is the category and one is product

```
category table
cat_id         category_name
1          animals
2          fruits
3          vegetables


product table
pro_id       category_id    product_name
1            2             mango
2            3             beans
3            2             apple
4            1             cat
```

i tried selecting cat id order by cat_id on category table
while cat table is looping....{
i tried selecting product on product table using cat_id
while product table is looping..{
i just want to put it in array in good format
}

}

example result is

```
        Array
        (
            [fruits] => Array
                (
from cat_id -->  [2] => Array
                        (
                            [pro_id] => 1
                            [name] => mango
                        )           
from cat_id -->  [2] => Array
                         (  [id] => 3
                            [name] => apple
                        )
                ),
            [vegetables] => Array
                (
from cat_id -->  [3] => Array
                        (
                            [pro_id] => 2
                            [name] => beans
                        )           

                ),
            [animals] => Array
                (
from cat_id -->  [1] => Array
                        (
                            [pro_id] => 4
                            [name] => cat
                        )           
                )       
         )
```

Comment: How are you getting that data from the database?

Comment: I use while($row_cat = mysql_fetch_array($result_cat){ then call product using while again and build an array. }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first retrieve the categories and loop through those, then retrieve the products for each category.  Something like:

```
$result = Array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_name";
// db query here (however you are doing that)
foreach ($categories as $category)
    {
    $result[$category['category_name']] = Array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_id = $category[cat_id] ORDER BY product_name";
    // db query here (however you are doing that)
    foreach ($products as $product)
        $result[$category['category_name']][$product['pro_id']] = $product['product_name'];
    }
```

This will give you output like:

```
Array(
    'fruits' => Array(
        1 => 'mango',
        3 => 'apple',
        )
     etc.
```

Tweak it as needed if you need to keep the category id, etc.

Comment: You mean to retrieved the category id, inside while($row_cat = mysql_fetch_array($result_cat)){ do i need to build array first? For cat id? Then use loop?}

Comment: No need for a while loop - just retrieve the list of categories using that first query and then loop through each category with the foreach loop.  Then you see I use a second query to retrieve the products for that category id, and loop over those using another foreach loop.